# Creating private route when isAuth comes from a callback

Tags: reactjs, authentication, callback, access-token, react-router-v4

I am using react router private routing system. I'm checking authentication, by getting **jwt from localstorage** and cross checking against server in an **axios promise**.

However the private routing does not seem to wait for callback to return.
Am i doing the authentication wrong? or is there a way of fixing this?

my axios promise to check auth.

```
const checkAuth = (cb) => {
    let token = localStorage.getItem("jwtToken");
    // console.log(token);
    if (token) {
        axios.defaults.headers.common["Authorization"] = token;
        axios
            .get("api/admin/auth/profile")
            .then(res => {
                localStorage.setItem("admin", res.data.admin);
                cb(null, res.data);
            })
            .catch(err => {
                showErr(err, cb);
            });
    } else {
        cb("Not authenticated", null);
    }
}
```

Private route set up.

```
const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest, checkAuth }) => 
(
    <Route {...rest} render={(props) => (
        checkAuth((isAuthenticated) => (
            isAuthenticated === true
            ? <Component {...props} />
            : <Redirect to={{
              pathname: '/login',
              state: { from: props.location }
            }} />
        ))
    )} />
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `checkAuth` method returns nothing. A render function should return a component. I'd suggest to create a stateful CheckAuth component like this.

```
class CheckAuth extends React.Component {
  state = {}

  componentDidMount () {
    this.props.checkAuth(isAuthenticated => {
      this.setState({isAuthenticated})
    })
  }

  render () {
     return this.props.children({loading, isAuthenticated})
  }
}

const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest, checkAuth }) => 
(
    <Route {...rest} render={(props) => 
      <CheckAuth {...props} checkAuth={checkAuth}>
       {({isAuthenticated}) => (
         isAuthenticated === true
         ? <Component {...props} />
         : <Redirect to={{
           pathname: '/login',
           state: { from: props.location }
        )}
      </CheckAuth>
    )}</Route>

}
```